# Converter svg para png java

Tags: java, svg

Estou tentando realizar uma conversão de imagem SGV para PNG, mas estou tendo alguns problemas.

Meu código:

```
   String svg_URI_input = Paths.get("/home/ivan/Documentos/imagem/Svg2.svg").toUri().toURL().toString();
    TranscoderInput input_svg_image = new TranscoderInput(svg_URI_input);        



    OutputStream png_ostream = new FileOutputStream("/home/ivan/Documentos/imagem/tica.png");
    TranscoderOutput output_png_image = new TranscoderOutput(png_ostream);              


    // Step-3: Create PNGTranscoder and define hints if required
    PNGTranscoder my_converter = new PNGTranscoder();        


    // Step-4: Convert and Write output
    my_converter.transcode(input_svg_image, output_png_image);


    // Step 5- close / flush Output Stream
    png_ostream.flush();
    png_ostream.close();       

}
```

Exceção:

```
on element <image> can't be opened because:
URL data in unsupported format or corrupt
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.UserAgentAdapter.getBrokenLinkDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGImageElementBridge.createRasterImageNode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGImageElementBridge.createImageGraphicsNode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGImageElementBridge.buildImageGraphicsNode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGImageElementBridge.createGraphicsNode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at convertsvgtopng.ConvertSvgToPng.main(ConvertSvgToPng.java:46)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: null
Enclosed Exception:
file:/home/ivan/Documentos/imagem/Svg2.svg:0

    on element <image> can't be opened because:
URL data in unsupported format or corrupt
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at convertsvgtopng.ConvertSvgToPng.main(ConvertSvgToPng.java:46)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: acredito que o problema esteja no caminho da imagem passada que pode estar com o formatação errada ou o caminho pode estar incompleto.

Answer (score 2):

Como dito pelo Dener, parece que o seu problema é de caminho até o arquivo.

Eu testei o seu programa e ele funcionou com caminhos completos, mas não funcionou com o `"/home"`.

Você pode tentar mudar o input para:

```
String svg_URI_input = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/Documentos/imagem/Svg2.svg").toUri().toURL().toString();
```

E o output para:

```
OutputStream png_ostream = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/Documentos/imagem/tica.png");
```

***As fontes para essa resposta foram encontradas em perguntas relacionadas no stackoverflow em inglês - [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10166623/1579771) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/494742/1579771).***